# specify and test htaccess HTTP_ACCEPT

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, http-accept-header

When I test my `.htaccess` with

```
curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" -L http://localhost/v0.1
curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" -L http://localhost/v1.0
```

This works

```
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.rdf [R=308,L]
```

But this doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml [R=308,L]
```

Without following redirection it returns:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://localhost/v1.0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   358  100   358    0     0  23866      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23866<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>308 Permanent Redirect</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Permanent Redirect</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

The full document is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
AddType application/rdf+xml .owl
AddType text/turtle .ttl
AddType application/n-triples .n3
AddType application/ld+json .json

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v0\.1/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/index.htm [R=308,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^v1\.0/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html [R=308,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/ld\+json
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.json [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.rdf [R=308,L]
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/n-triples
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.nt [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/turtle
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.ttl [R=308,L]
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} .+
RewriteRule ^$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/406.html [R=406,L]

# Default response
RewriteRule ^$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml [R=308,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found what's wrong with your file. You are assuming that the "RewriteCond" that you have written for your first "RewriteRule" applies to the second one as well.

However, this is not the case: you should repeat the condition for the second rule. For example, you have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v0\.1/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/index.htm [R=308,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^v1\.0/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html [R=308,NE,L]
```

But in order to work properly, you should have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/index.htm [R=308,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html [R=308,NE,L]
```

If you don't, then it takes the rule without conditions, and serves the HTML every time you ask for "v1.0", as it happens in your curl command.

I have tested locally the following file, and works successfully:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
AddType application/rdf+xml .owl
AddType text/turtle .ttl
AddType application/n-triples .n3
AddType application/ld+json .json

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/index.htm [R=308,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html [R=308,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/ld\+json
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.json [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.rdf [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/n-triples
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.nt [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/turtle
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.ttl [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/turtle
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl [R=308,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} .+
RewriteRule ^$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/406.html [R=406,L]

# Default response
RewriteRule ^$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/clo
```

When doing:

```
curl -sH "Accept:text/turtle" http://localhost/redirectTest2/v1.0
```

I get:

```
<html><head>
<title>308 Permanent Redirect</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Permanent Redirect</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```